# Path issue while Configuring babel-cli

Tags: reactjs, command-line, babeljs, lite-server, babel-cli

I recently started working with ReactJS. So I was following a tutorial which shows how to configure babel-cli. So with it, I've installed all necessary packages including liter-server. 
I understood and implemented pretty much everything same but, while executing a command that specified the path in the project making a problem
 [image: Project Structure]

i.e I've installed my lite-server and when I execute this command in the root of my project 
**lite-server -d ./dist -p 3000** I'm getting 404. i.e In browser when I enter localhost:3000 I'm getting *Cannot GET /* But when I redirect to dist and type this command 
**lite-server -p 3000**.
What's wrong with **./dist**? I'm in relative path and it should work fine as it is working pretty well in the tutorial.

Comment: According to docs you should use `--baseDir="dist"` option

Comment: Can you refer to link? or If I'm in top of my project hierarchy, what should be the command? Could you elaborate?

Comment: In your `package.json` change start script to `lite-server --baseDir=dist` Port will be 3000 by default.

Comment: use webpack-dev-server with webpack much better option :)